# How do I get my database to not append the status when I do an api call?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

So I'm trying to create a simple blog app using the MEAN stack.  I am able to successfully write to my local mongo DB but when I make a call to my DB, it appends additional information to my query which makes it hard to ng-repeat.  Here's what the response look like:

```
[{"_id":"135","title":"aaaaaa","body":"aaaaaa","__v":0,"posted":"2017-08-05T08:46:27.159Z"},
{"_id":"136","title":"bbbbb","body":"bbbbb","__v":0,"posted":"2017-08-05T08:46:40.232Z"}]
200
function (d){b||(b=vd(a));return d?(d=b[Q(d)],void 0===d&&(d=null),d):b}
{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"/api/blogpost","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}}
OK
```

I just want the first two elements with "aaaa" and "bbbb" in the object so I can use ng-repeat to get the title, body, etc. This is how I'm displaying the information on my index.html:

```
<input ng-model="post.title" class="form-control" placeholder="title">
<textarea ng-model="post.body" class="form-control" placeholder="body"></textarea>
<button ng-click="createPost(post)" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Post</button>
<div ng-repeat="post in posts">
     {{post}}
</div>
```

Here's how my Angular get code looks:

```
    function getAllPosts() {
        $http({
            method: 'get',
            url: '/api/blogpost'
        }).then( function (posts){
            $scope.posts = posts;
        }, function (error){
            console.error("Inside app.js._getAllPosts().error");
        });
    }
```

And here is my backend:

```
app.get("/api/blogpost", getAllPosts);

function getAllPosts(req, res) {
var post = req.body;
PostModel
    .find()
    .then(
        function (post) {
            res.json(post);
        },
        function (error) {
            res.sendStatus(400);
        }
    );
}
```

I can post the rest of my code if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to reference the `data` property on your [success callback](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http):

```
}).then(function(response) {
    $scope.posts = response.data;
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

Use the key name to access the specific object.

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts">
{{post.title}} {{post.body}}
</div>
```